# Laravel & VueJS variable definition

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade, vue.js

I decided to create a little project using Laravel 5.1, vueJS (with vue-resource) and some file interaction on the server-side.

Everything works fine but in the process of creating the app I questioned myself what the best way of receiving data from the server was. Besides the ovious solution, AJAX, I tried writing the data with laravel-blade inside the data object of my Vue instance, which looked like this:

FileController.php:

```
$files = Auth::user()->files;
return view('files.index', compact('files'));
```

The files() function is just a simple belongsToMany() relationship on the User Model with a pivot table in the background.

index.blade.php:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#files',
  data: {
    // pass the data to Vue via PHP so you don't need an AJAX request
    files: {!! $files !!}

  //  ..
}
```

The other solution would be something like this in my Vue instance:

```
ready: function() {
  this.$http.get('/todos', function (data) {
    this.$set('todos', data);
  }).error(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Now my question is whether or not my approach has any disadvantages because in my opinion it's better because it's less AJAX interaction and that means the app should be faster (at least in theory).

Edit: of course it's possible to simply write it with a blade foreach for example but I want to do the presentation of the data in vue.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the data using the props:

```
<div id="files" :files="{{ $files }}"></div>
```

And in your `Vue` instance:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#files",
    props: ['files'],
    data: {
        list: []
    },
    ready: {
        this.list = JSON.parse(this.files)
    }
});
```

The props option `files` is filled by the `$files` from `laravel`, and is parsed to `json` to use in `vue`, after the ready option, you can use in `HTML`:

```
<div v-for="l in list">
    @{{ l.name }}
    @{{ l.last_name }}
</div>
```

The list contains the `json` with the files that comes from `Laravel` controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need [props](http://vuejs.org/api/#props)

So your element will look like:

```
<div id="#files" :files="{!! $files !!}"></div>
```

And your Vue:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#files',
    props: {
        files: {
            type: Object // <- not necessary, you can also have props: ['files']
        }
    }  
});
```